Constructing a map that is not nullhomotopic
I need some help on the following questions relating to nullhomotopic maps:
For $n\ge 2$, let $r\colon S^1\rightarrow S^1$ be the rotation $r(\cos \phi, \sin\phi) = (\cos(\phi+2\pi/n),\sin(\phi + 2\pi/n))$ and let $X_n$ be the quotient space obtained from the disk $D^2$ by identifying each point $x\in S^1$ with the points $r(x),~r^2(x),~\cdots,r^{n-1}(x)$.
(a) Construct a map $f\colon S^1\rightarrow X_n$ that is not nullhomotopic.
(b) Show that every map $g\colon X_n \rightarrow S^1$ is nullhomotopic.
Regarding the (a) part, I was thinking of using the Characterization of nullhomotopic maps by trying to construct $f$ that cannot be extended to $D^2$ but I am not getting anywhere with that. I would appreciate any guidance on how to make such construction and to prove the (b) part too.

Let's begin by trying to visualize what the space $X_n$ looks like. For $n = 2$, we are identifying each point on the circle with its antipodal counterpart. Recall that this space is more commonly known as $\mathbb RP^2$, or the real projective plane. That's neat. What about $n = 3$? Well, clearly if $\psi, \phi$ are two distinct angles between $0 \leq \phi, \psi < 2 \pi/3$ radians (between 0 and 120 degrees), then $(\cos \phi,\sin \phi)$ and $(\cos \psi, \sin \psi)$ lie in distinct equivalence classes under the identification resulting in $X_3$. Moreover, such angles give every possible representative of the boundary in the quotient space. Try to convince yourself that the space we have obtained is homeomorphic to the one we would obtain by taking $(S^1 \sqcup D^2)/\varphi$ where $\varphi: \partial D^2 \to S^1$ is the map that wraps the boundary of the disk thrice around the circle. If this notation or method of constructing spaces is new to you, you may want to have a look at Hatcher's discussion of Van Kampen's theorem in his book titled Algebraic Topology.
In general, $X_n$ would be the space obtained by gluing the boundary of the disk onto the circle by wrapping it $n$ times around the circle. Results from the aforementioned section (cf. Proposition 1.26 or Example 1.29 in the online edition) should reveal why the fundamental group of this space has to be $\mathbb Z/ n\mathbb Z$. Can you figure out why this implies every map $X_n \to S^1$ must be nullhomotopic? Think in terms of the induced homomorphism between the fundamental groups.
As for part (a), again, it's always a good idea to begin small, perhaps with $n = 2, 3$. Successfully visualizing the space will help you build the map. Are you familiar with the presentation of the projective plane by identifying the edges of a square? Can you do the same for $X_n$ with some polygon?
Since I don't have enough reputation to comment, I'll pose the questions I wish to ask here. Which result are you referring to by the characterization of nullhomotopic maps? Could you also please tell us where you found this problem so we can better tailor our answers to your background?

To answer one of your questions, the characterization of nullhomotopic maps referred to is almost surely "A map $S^1 \to X$ extends to a map $D^2 \to X$ ($X$ any space) iff it is nullhomotopic."

@Posetologist, is $X_n$ the same as the space obtained by attaching $n-$cell to $S^1$?

Part $\textbf{a)}$ is exhaustively answered by Posetologist.
For part $\textbf{b)}$ I would like to give you $2$ different solution, in case you are not able to figure one out (or just curious) from the hint.
$X_n$ has a finite fundamental group. That means that each map $f$ functorially sends $\pi_1(X_n)$ in the $0$ subgroup of $\pi_1(S^1)$. With that we know that every such map surely satisfies the lifting condition to a cover of $S^1$: we have a contractible one (namely $\mathbb{R}$) and so every map is nullhomotopic because it can be factored through a map landing in a contractible space.
This was not the thing I wanted to show: I would like to give you another approach using Yoneda's lemma (or rather one of its [not so direct] consequence: Brown representation theorem).
It states that (I am simplifying things here) the cohomology functor is representable and it is represented via the homotopy class of maps landing in an appropriate Eilenberg-Maclane space.
By the consideration above (on the finiteness of the fundamental group of $X_n$) we know
$$Hom(\pi_1(X_n), \mathbb{Z})=0.$$
We also notice that, being $\mathbb{Z}$ commutative, this is implies
$$Hom(\pi_1 ^ {ab} (X_n), \mathbb{Z})=Hom(H_1 (X_n), \mathbb{Z})=0$$
and the latter is just $H^1 (X_n)$. By the theorem, $H^1 (X_n)=[X_n, K(\mathbb{Z}, 1)]$ but a model of a $K(\mathbb{Z}, 1)$ space is $S^1 \Rightarrow$
$$0=Hom(\pi_1 (X), \mathbb{Z})=H^1 (X_n)=[X_n , S^1]\Rightarrow$$
each map is nullhomotopic.
